# Fixing a Double Render Error when creating more than one object with one request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I have a controller action that takes in an array. It iterates through the array and should make a new object of each element in the array. But when I attempt this now I get a double render error? Anyone know how I can fix this?

### Controller

```
    def create
      params[:emails].each do |email|
      # Ignore if the user is already on the account.
      if current_account.users.exists?(email: email) || current_account.invitations.exists?(email: email)
        flash[:alert] = "#{email} is already on the team"
        redirect_to account_users_path

        return
      end

      invitation = Invitation.new({
        account: current_account,
        inviter: current_user,
        email:   email,
      })

      if invitation.save
        Notifier.invite(invitation).deliver_later
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Email is invalid"
      end

      redirect_to account_users_path
    end
  end
```

As you can see I iterate over the emails and try to make a new object out of each. But right now I get this error.

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Accounts::InvitationsController#create
```

Comment: Well yes, don't render or redirect in each iteration. Figure out what's the appropriate action is and do that __after__ the loop.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I knew that of course but it's early here. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `redirect_to` call outside the loop:

```
def create
  params[:emails].each do |email|
    # Ignore if the user is already on the account.
    if current_account.users.exists?(email: email) || current_account.invitations.exists?(email: email)
      flash[:alert] = "#{email} is already on the team"
      redirect_to account_users_path

      return
    end

    invitation = Invitation.new({
      account: current_account,
      inviter: current_user,
      email:   email,
    })

    if invitation.save
      Notifier.invite(invitation).deliver_later
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Email is invalid"
    end
  end
  redirect_to account_users_path
end
```